# Not counting all of the numbers from previous file? Python

Tags: file, python-3.x

The problem I encounter with my code is that after opening the file, it only counts the last number randomly generated and does not add all of them up. For example, if you use the amount of numbers as 2, it will only show the last number generated instead of all of them. Here is the prompt:

Write a program that writes a series of random numbers to a file. Each random number should be in the range of 1 through 500. The application should let the user specify how many numbers the file will hold. The next program should read the random numbers from the file, display the numbers, and then display the total of the numbers and the number of numbers read from the file.

```
# import the random module
import random

# open the file to write to
random_numbers = open('ran_numbers.txt', 'w')
# ask for numbers written to the file
numberOfNumbers = int(input("How many numbers do you want written to the file?: "))
print("Your random numbers are: ")
# number selection
for count in range (numberOfNumbers):
    number = random.randint(1,500)
    print(number)
# writing numbers to file with new line after
random_numbers.write(str(number)+ '\n')
# close
random_numbers.close()

random_numbers = open('ran_numbers.txt', 'r')
number = 0
total = 0
print("List of numbers:")
for line in random_numbers.readlines():
        print(line)
        total = total+int(line)
        number +=1
print("The Sum of the numbers = "+str(total))
print("The total amount of numbers read are "+str(number))
```

Comment: move the `raneom_numbers.write(str(number)+'\n'` line inside the loop. For Python, that means, indent it. You would probably spend less time stepping through the execution and finding your error than you did posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just indent 4 spaces to the statement "random_numbers.write(str(number)+ '\n')" so that it comes under the for loop. Then you will get your required output. What is happening actually is you are writing only the last number to your file because your writing statement is out of the for loop.